# Get iso from Windows Secure Download Manager

Tags: windows-8

I'm installing a copy of Windows 8 and the only install media I received was in the form of a download though something called the Secure Download Manager. See screenshot.

Which immediately starts an upgrade style install. Having been on this board for about a week, I am sure I want to do a clean install.

How can I get an iso from the Secure Download Manager?

[image: Secure Download Manager]

Comment: I reopened your question for now but I would encourage you to outline your purchase and download process in more detail (by [edit]ing your question). Most people will have purchased Windows 8 from the Microsoft store and will not be familiar with your way of purchase.

Comment: What is in Downloads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, the Secure Download Manager uses a .sdx-file to take care of downloading the piece(s) of software described in that file, probably in a secure manner, as the name of the application implies.

When the download is completed, the file(s) should be located in the specified download location. Based in your image, it seems to be located inside "C:\Users[your username]\Downloads" in your case.

You can either open (or do whatever you want to do with) the file inside that folder, or you can use the "Launch" button in the manager.

If the downloaded file is not a .iso-file, then you need to look elsewhere to get a .iso-file. If the .sdx-file is for downloading a .exe-file, then that's how the story goes...

Is it important that the file **must** be a .iso-file? From the image, it looks like you are going to upgrade from Win7 to Win8 or something along those lines. Even if the file is a .exe-file, it should still be able to do that.

Comment: It started the upgrade right away, every-time I click on the exe, it just starts the download and goes straight to upgrade. Makes me sad.

Comment: Are you trying to say that the Secure Download Manager just downloads again, or does the Windows 8 Upgrade start and download stuff?
As far as I can remember, Windows 8 does some extra downloads/updates before actually installing (or in your case, upgrading) itself. Could that be it?

In other words, can you get the installer to run, and if yes, what happens next? :-)

Comment: The Windows upgrade starts and downloads stuff, the time it takes it download is very long.

Comment: Ok, what happens when its done downloading?

Answer (score 1):

You need to launch the secure download manager (as it says) to get the .iso

It will download the ISO image to whichever folder you provide.

Comment: For me it launches a standalone exe that begins downloading, after getting the install information, it starts an upgrade.

Comment: Hmmm - you should be offered the option to either download the iso (for later install) or install now.

Answer (score 0):

You will notice in your screenshot a Download Location, that is where your ISO is saved at. At least based on my experience with the MSDN Student account I had. I usually just kept it default which was a folder in C:\